# What does select("device") do in Spark query?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In [`Spark documentation`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-operations---selection-projection-aggregation) there is an example

```
df = ...  # streaming DataFrame with IOT device data with schema { device: string, deviceType: string, signal: double, time: DateType }

# Select the devices which have signal more than 10
df.select("device").where("signal > 10")
```

What does `select("device")` part do?

If it is a selection by `signal` field value, then why to mention `device` field?

Why don't write just

```
df.where("signal > 10")
```

or

```
df.select("time").where("signal > 10")
```

?

Comment: It selects only one column "device" and ignore all others where "signal > 10", whereas df.where("signal > 10") will select all columns where signal > 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select("device")
```

this only select the Column "device"

```
df.show
+----------+-------------------+
|signal    | B | C | D | E | F |
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|10        | 4 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 
|15        | 6 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+

 df.select("device").show
+----------+
|signal    |
+----------+
|10        |
|15        |
+----------+
```